# How to pass a widget object to a function in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, function, object, reference

I am fairly new to Qt and would be grateful if anyone could help me with this issue.
I am using Qt Creator and created a form with a `PlainTextEdit`. I am trying to use an if statement to validate the text entered in this text box. I made a function like the following

```
void validateText (QPlainTextEdit *myWidget)
{
    if ((myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("1")) ||
        (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("2")) ||
        (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("3")) ||
        (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("4")) ||
        (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("5")) ||
        (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("6")) ||
        (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("7")) ||
        (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("8")) ||
        (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("9")) ||
        (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("0"))
    )
    {
        qDebug() << "Integer entered";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Non-integer entered";
    }
}
```

However, when I call this function from the `on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()` slot, I get an  error:

```
undefined reference to validateText(QPlainTextEdit*)
```

Currently, I have this code so far in the textchanged slot:

```
void Options::on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()
{
    validateText(qobject_cast<QPlainTextEdit*>(qApp->widgetAt(180,30)));
}
```

As you can see I am trying to get a reference to the object itself and pass it on to the function but I am having issues with this. Am I doing something wrong, or is there an easier way of passing a widget object to a function in Qt?

Comment: I've never used `qobject_cast` but I suspect it's not meant for pointers. Have you tried using `static_cast` instead?

Comment: A different approach would be to make your validateText function a member function of a validator class. The validator class could take a pointer to a QPlainTextEdit in its constructor (and store this pointer in a member variable) and set up all the necessary connections of signals and slots.

Comment: Yes I did try `static_cast` but I still get same error

Comment: Hmm, adding a validator class sounds like a better option. I am going to give that a try. Thanks for your comment Daniel.

Comment: If you solved your problem, make it an answer instead. You are allowed and encouraged to do so. Once a certain time is over, you can simply accept it. Then we have a question and answer. This is a Q&A after all. ;)

Comment: Well, I tried but since I am a new user and have less than 10 rep it wont let me do it for 8 hours or so. I just edited the main message for the time being. Thanks though :)

Comment: Ok, glad to hear that you got it working. Just remember to create an answer once you have the permissions required.

Comment: @Dohz As a tip, you should really store the result of `toPlainText()` to a local `QString` variable instead of getting a copy of the string over and over in your `validateText()` method. Then all your conditions look like `myWidgetText.endsWith("1")`. Easier to read, maintain, refactor, and runs faster. Win win.

Comment: @Bret Ah didn't even notice that. Thanks for the advice, i'll keep that in mind for the future as well :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, as suggested by Daniel in the comments, I added a validator class and that fixed the issue I was having. Here is the code for anyone having the same problem in the future.

**validator.cpp**

```
...
Validator::Validator(QPlainTextEdit *textEdit)
{
    this->myWidget = textEdit;
}
void Validator::validateText ()
{
    if (   (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("1")) ||
           (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("2")) ||
           (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("3")) ||
           (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("4")) ||
           (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("5")) ||
           (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("6")) ||
           (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("7")) ||
           (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("8")) ||
           (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("9")) ||
           (myWidget->toPlainText().endsWith("0"))
        )
    {
        qDebug() << "Integer entered";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Non-integer entered";
    }
}
```

And the function call

```
void Options::on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()
{
    Validator* val = new Validator(ui->plainTextEdit);
    val->validateText();
}
```

This completely skipped the need to cast from QWidget to a QPlainTextEdit or any of that nonsense.

Comment: This might be a little late, but you are creating a new `Validator` object every time text is changed, and you are never destroying it. Don't make it a pointer, and it will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope. Or create it dynamically in your constructor, so it will be only created once.